# How can I get the text from this HTML code with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#https://nl.indeed.com/vacatures?q=python%20developer%20%E2%82%AC30.000&vjk=7074ca9832f39591
with open("INDEED.html", encoding="utf8") as f:
    source = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
box1 = source.find_all("div", class_="job_seen_beacon")
for box2 in box1:
    title = box2.find("h2", class_="jobTitle")
    company = box2.find("span", class_="companyName")
    salary = box2.find("div", class_="metadata salary-snippet-container")
    print(title.text)
    print(company.text)
    print(salary)
```

I can get the [title] and [company] info as text, however I can't do the same with [salary].
How can I print out the [salary] as text, from this code/content? (salary info located at the end of the code)

```
Full Stack Software Developer
Hello Energy
<div class="metadata salary-snippet-container"><div class="attribute_snippet"><svg aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Salary" fill="none" role="presentation" viewbox="0 0 16 13" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs></defs><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M2.45168 6.10292c-.30177-.125-.62509-.18964-.95168-.1903V4.08678c.32693-.00053.6506-.06518.95267-.1903.30331-.12564.57891-.30979.81105-.54193.23215-.23215.4163-.50775.54194-.81106.12524-.30237.18989-.62638.19029-.95365H9.0902c0 .3283.06466.65339.1903.9567.12564.30331.30978.57891.54193.81106.23217.23215.50777.41629.81107.54193.3032.12558.6281.19024.9562.1903v1.83556c-.3242.00155-.6451.06616-.9448.19028-.3033.12563-.5789.30978-.81102.54193-.23215.23214-.4163.50774-.54193.81106-.12332.2977-.18789.61638-.19024.93849H3.99496c-.00071-.32645-.06535-.64961-.19029-.95124-.12564-.30332-.30979-.57891-.54193-.81106-.23215-.23215-.50775-.4163-.81106-.54193zM0 .589843C0 .313701.223858.0898438.5.0898438h12.0897c.2762 0 .5.2238572.5.5000002V9.40715c0 .27614-.2238.5-.5.5H.5c-.276143 0-.5-.22386-.5-.5V.589843zM6.54427 6.99849c1.10457 0 2-.89543 2-2s-.89543-2-2-2-2 .89543-2 2 .89543 2 2 2zm8.05523-2.69917v7.10958H2.75977c-.27615 0-.5.2238-.5.5v.5c0 .2761.22385.5.5.5H15.422c.4419 0 .6775-.2211.6775-.6629V4.29932c0-.27615-.2239-.5-.5-.5h-.5c-.2761 0-.5.22385-.5.5z" fill="#595959" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>€4.000 - €5.000 per maand</div></div>
```

Comment: I think you just have to get the child _div_ inside the _div_ you are selecting and then selecting the text attribute (with _.text_) from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all of the entries have a salary entry, you should test for this. For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

req = requests.get("https://nl.indeed.com/vacatures?q=python%20developer%20%E2%82%AC30.000&vjk=7074ca9832f39591")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

for div_job_seen in soup.find_all("div", class_="job_seen_beacon"):
    title = div_job_seen.find("h2", class_="jobTitle")
    company = div_job_seen.find("span", class_="companyName")
    salary = div_job_seen.find("div", class_="salary-snippet")
    
    print(title.text)
    print(company.text)
    
    if salary:
        print(salary.text)
        
    print('---------')
```

Would give you the following entries:

```
Python Developer
xxllnc
---------
Senior Python Developer
Shopping Minds
---------
Senior python developer
Movares
€3.500 - €5.000 per maand
---------
Python Developer
Zaaksysteem.nl
---------
Backend Software Developer
Stream
€28 per uur
---------
Software Developer
Kasto Service
---------
Software Developer
NKI-AVL
€36 per uur
---------
Python Developer Crypto
Search X Recruitment
€90.000 - €110.000 per jaar
---------
Python Developer
The NextGen
---------
Python Developer
Techonomy
---------
Python Developer
Veneficus
€3.500 per maand
---------
Senior Python Software Developer
Flora Logistics
---------
Python Developer
Python People
---------
nieuwPython Ontwikkelaar
BeNext
€2.500 per maand
---------
Python developer
Prosafco
```

Comment: Thank you @MartinEvans  (and of course for all of you, who tried to help me!)
It was not necessary to rewrite the whole code, only this part helped me to solve the problem: 
"if salary:
        print(salary.text)
        
    print('---------')

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_text() method or css selector

```
print(salary.get_text(strip=True))

#OR 

salary = box2.select_one(".metadata.salary-snippet-containe div")
salary=salary.text if salary else None
```

Comment: I tried both version, but unfortunately it doesn't work, as I got the following feedback: 
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'"  and  salary = box2.select_one(".metadata.salary-snippet-container div").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @AdamV I've updated

Comment: Thank you @F.Hoque for the answer. If I add the whole part of each code, it will not work for me, however if I would add just the line "salary=salary.text if salary else None" to my original code, then it's working perfectly.